# Add a delay to ember fixture data to simulate ajax

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I'm using [Ember fixtures](http://emberjs.com/guides/models/the-fixture-adapter/) to prototype my app, and I'd like to add a delay the first time a model is requested to simulate an ajax request. Is this possible?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Good question. The [`FixtureAdapter`](https://github.com/emberjs/data/blob/master/packages/ember-data/lib/adapters/fixture_adapter.js#L29) has that exact feature built-in, the property you need to configure is called `latency`. Try this:

```
App.Store = DS.Store.extend({
  adapter: DS.FixtureAdapter.create({ latency: 5000 });
});
```

This will add a delay of 5000 millis (5 seconds) to the [`FixtureAdapter`](https://github.com/emberjs/data/blob/master/packages/ember-data/lib/adapters/fixture_adapter.js#L29), waiting 5 seconds before it returns the data.

Although @Daniel's answer is also a valid approach, but using this built-in feature will let your model hook's untouched which will require no effort at all when you switch to a different Adapter at some point, and there will be no need to remove the simulating promises resulting in cleaner code.

Hope it helps.

Comment: ARgh, documentation strikes again!

Answer (score 4):

**In your model hook return a promise that resolves after a short delay.**

```
 model: function(params, transition){

    return new Ember.RSVP.Promise(function(resolve){
        setTimeout(function(){ 
            var model =  App.Model.find(params.id);
            resolve(model);
        }, 3000); // 3 second delay, wooh, your server is slow!!!
    });
 }
```

Comment: I tried this, but it didn't save the model in the store. I'd like to simulate the delay only the first time the model is requested.

Comment: You need to use this general solution when you are not using Ember Data. With Ember Data use the solution by intuitivepixel.